# In visual studio code how to keybind in the combination [alt + ctrl + '] the key [`]?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-snippets

In visual studio code

How to keybind in the combination  <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>  to output a backtick <kbd>`</kbd> as a quote?

I'm searching the specific command to put in the **keybindings.json**

```
{
    "key": "alt+ctrl+\'",
    "command": "????????????command?????????????",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to output a backtick <kbd>`</kbd>

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+'",

    // "command": "type",       // normally this would work
    // "args": {"text":"`"},

    // "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",  // this outs just one backtick
    // "args": {
    //   "snippet": "`"
    // },

  "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "`$TM_SELECTED_TEXT`"   // use this to wrap selected text with backticks
  },

    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
 },
```

Normally, the `type` command is what you would use here, but since it outputs a backtick vscode automatically adds another - just like typing one <kbd>"</kbd> outputs two.  Unless you set your `Editor > Auto Closing Quotes` setting to `never`, but that will affect all quotes, not just backticks.

So if you only want one backtick, use the `insertSnippet` command version - it only outputs one backtick.

Comment: When I use one of those two methods VSC inserts the backtick character but does not treat it as a type of quote, so if I highlight a word and do my combination it replaces the word with the character instead of making me the typical append and postpend.

Comment: Ah, that is different - you want to surround selected text with backticks?  If so, I amended the answer.